# creating installer package with mysql c#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, installation

I have a winform application written in C#. My database stands in MySql. Now i wanted it to deploy on other machines without having to install mysql individually/saperately on each machine. Please suggest me ways i could include my MySql database with the application in one installer without having to install mysql on each machine. Alternatively if its not possible in MySql i could migrate it in Sqlite. Please point me to relevant resources.

I have seen similar questions on this board before but none of them was clear in their solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When faced with a similar situation I simply included a MySQL distribution with the application (this was for internal purposes, you may need a license to distribute MySQL commercially).

Here's what I did:

- I installed a MySQL server on a local machine. I configured it so that the data folder and the configuration file reside in the same folder as the rest of the MySQL server. I then created the database, an user, and filled the database with relevant data.
- I included the entire MySQL folder in the installer. The installer would simply copy this folder to the application's destination folder.
- I could then start MySQL like this: `{app_folder}\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="{app_folder}\my.ini"`. To stop MySQL I used: `{app_folder}\mysql\bin\mysqladmin.exe -u youruser -p yourpassword shutdown`. You could have your application check if MySQL is running and start it if not.

This might not be the best solution since anyone could easily access the database. Also I cannot confirm if this would work with the current versions of MySQL (you may need to specify the data folder in the configuration file). If the database is only used by your application SQLite might be a better option.

Comment: Hello Sir, now I am also facing same problem. I have 2 .exe file one is for client machine and 2nd is for admin machine both are network connected. I have already developed WPF windows app with SQLite db. How can I access the db from admin machine to other client machine?

Comment: I have already developed WPF windows app with SQLite db. Alternatively if its not possible in Sqlite i could migrate it in MySql. May I need a licence(paid) to distribute  MySQL commercially ? I can not use paid one database. Actually, I wanted it to deploy on other machines without having to install mysql individually/saperately on each machine.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you could use the "[Prerequisites in Windows Installer Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eh4aaa5.aspx)"

So you add mysql installer as prerequisities and after you can install your application and execute the script for the Database creation and other resource like Table, Views and Stored Procedure.

[This tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49b92ztk.aspx) can help you on the second step.